# How to set default values for fields in Realm for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, realm

I want to specify default values for my fields using Realm. If I set these values in the constructor, it doesn't work. Is there any API method for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a limitation of Realm for Xamarin, as stated in the documentation, specifically in the section **Current Limitations**:

> Default values – the standard way of defining them is not compatible with the weaving